# SQL where clause getting ignored

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

```
pf_master
temp_table
```

pf_master layout is

```
username
pf_name
pf_id
```

and the data in pf_master is

```
username  pf_name  pf_id
-------------------------
xyz       General  3
xyz       Overall  0
abc       General  3
```

temp table layout is

```
pf_id
inv_val
curr_val
xirr
loginid
timestamp
```

and the values in temp table are

```
pf_id   inv_val   curr_val    xirr    loginid    timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0       100       200         10%     xyz        2019-04-06 12:21:28
3       100       300         11%     xyz        2019-04-06 12:21:40
```

I want to fetch all records of 'abc' user along with the pf_name. But 'abc' does not have any records in temp_table so ideally this query should return a NULL. But it is returning the value of 'xyz' user.

My SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    pf_master.pf_name, 
    temp_table.inv_val, temp_table.curr_val, temp_table.xirr 
FROM 
    temp_table 
INNER JOIN 
    pf_master ON pf_master.pf_id = temp_table.pf_id 
WHERE 
    pf_master.username = 'abc' 
ORDER BY 
    pf_master.pf_id ASC
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are joining the two tables solely on `pf_id`. You probably want to join the tables on `username = loginid` as well.

Comment: Since your JOIN is keying on the `pf_id`, it's pretty clear looking at your tables that `abc` has an `pf_id` of 3, and temp table contains records with `pf_id` of 3 to match. That's why you are not getting NULL in your current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the username as well as the pf_id in your join as pf_id by itself isn't enough to identify a unique user.

```
 SELECT 
        pf_master.pf_name, 
        temp_table.inv_val, 
        temp_table.curr_val,
        temp_table.xirr 
    FROM temp_table t
    JOIN pf_master  p 
      ON p.pf_id = t.pf_id 
     AND p.username = t.loginid
    WHERE 
        p.username = 'abc' 
    ORDER BY 
        p.pf_id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

First, fetch all records from pf_master where username = 'abc'

```
SELECT * FROM pf_master WHERE username = 'abc'
```

Then change INNER_JOIN clause in your question, instead of entire table pf_master you should use only result from fetching

Something like this:

```
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM pf_master WHERE username = 'abc') AS tmp ON tmp.pf_id = tmp_table.pf_id
```

Comment: There is no underscore between `INNER` and `JOIN` in `INNER JOIN`.